# Delphi DirectoryExists() won't detect folder correctly

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am currently running Delphi 2010 and whenever I try to run this it always returns that the folder exists even when it doesn't. I'm trying to replace the Registry.pol with a pre-configured one for testing.

```
    procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      ResStream: TResourceStream;
    begin
      if DirectoryExists('C:\WINDOWS\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine') then
        begin
          ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'AutoRestartWindowsDefault', RT_RCDATA);
          ResStream.SaveToFile('C:\WINDOWS\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol');
          ResStream.Free;
        end
      else
      begin
        ShellExecute(Handle, 'runas', 'cmd.exe', '/K md C:\WINDOWS\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Are you sure the folder doesn't exist? Can you do a `ChDir('C:\WINDOWS\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine')` right before that line?

Comment: 32 bit machine?

Comment: 32bit and 64bit computers have different locations, as @SertacAkyuz hints.

Comment: On an 64 bit machine, with D2010, you'll be directed to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\GroupPolicy\Machine" by default.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to do this but by far shelling out to a 64 bit process is theost robust

Comment: ChDir did not work and both computers I tested on had a copy of 64bit Windows 10. The location for this file is correct, because I have manually edited it before with it working. How do I need to force it to System32? I checked SysWOW64 and the file it copied is there.

Comment: That is your answer then. Admittedly you haven't asked a question yet though.

Comment: @KevinCowley on a 64bit system, `System32` is 64bit and `SysWOW64` is 32bit. If a 32bit process wants to access the 64bit `System32` folder, it can use the special `sysnative` alias to bypass redirection. See [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) for more details.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Linked above. Read the answers there.

Comment: Okay, thank you everyone. I got the answer I was looking for and updated the main post with the correct method.